# How to plot a graph out of two arrays with the x axis will be the length of the two arrays?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, data-science

```
array1=[1,2,3,4]
array2=[5,6,7,8]

plt.plot(4, array1, 'g', label='Label 1')
plt.plot(4, array2, 'b', label='Label 2')
plt.title('Sample Graph')
plt.xlabel('X Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But when I run this it says

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (4,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 is just an int. What you need is a list of 1-4

```py
plt.plot(range(1,5), array1, 'g', label='Label 1')
plt.plot(range(1,5), array2, 'b', label='Label 2')
```

Output:

[image: output]